# How to check if a string contains an URL

Tags: iphone, nsstring

i have text message and I want to check whether it is containing text "http" or URL exists in that.

How will I check it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSString *string = @"xxx http://someaddress.com";
NSString *substring = @"http:";
```

Case sensitive example:

```
NSRange textRange = [string rangeOfString:substring];

if(textRange.location != NSNotFound){
    //Does contain the substring
}else{
    //Does not contain the substring
}
```

Case insensitive example:

```
NSRange textRange = [[string lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[substring lowercaseString]];

if(textRange.location != NSNotFound){
    //Does contain the substring
}else{
    //Does not contain the substring
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Cyprian offers a good option.

You could also consider using a [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW48) which would give you far more flexibility assuming that's what you need, e.g. if you wanted to match http:// and https://.

Answer (score 0):

Url usually has http or https in it

You can use your custom method  containsString to check for those strings.

```
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)string {
    return [self containsString:string caseSensitive:NO];
}
- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString*)string caseSensitive:(BOOL)caseSensitive {
    BOOL contains = NO;
    if (![NSString isNilOrEmpty:self] && ![NSString isNilOrEmpty:string]) {
        NSRange range;
        if (!caseSensitive) {
            range =  [self rangeOfString:string options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        } else {
            range =  [self rangeOfString:string];
        }
        contains = (range.location != NSNotFound);
    }

    return contains;
}
```

Example :

```
[yourString containsString:@"http"]

[yourString containsString:@"https"]
```